# Avoid confliction of same packages in two diffrent jars

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I developed an OSGI bundle for five jars

```
poi-3.9 - bundle name:- org.apache.poi
poi-ooxml-3.9- bundle name:- org.apache.poi.ooxml
poi-ooxml-schemas
dom4j
xmlbeans
```

but when i use these jars it will give an error

```
NoClassDef found 
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
```

Then i realized some packages (like org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel) in

```
poi-3.9
poi-ooxml-3.9 jars are same 
then i use 
Require-Bundle: 
 org.apache.poi;visibility:=reexport,
 org.apache.poi.ooxml;visibility:=reexport
```

It will give an same error
What can I do to resolve this problem

Manifest File

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 1
Bundle-Name: poi
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.poi
Bundle-Version: 3.9
Bundle-Vendor: XYZ
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Import-Package: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel
Export-Package: org.apache.poi,
org.apache.poi.common.usermodel,
org.apache.poi.ddf,
org.apache.poi.dev,
org.apache.poi.hpsf,
org.apache.poi.hpsf.extractor,
org.apache.poi.hpsf.wellknown,
org.apache.poi.hssf,
org.apache.poi.hssf.dev,
org.apache.poi.hssf.eventmodel,
org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel,
org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.dummyrecord,
org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor,
org.apache.poi.hssf.model,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.cf,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.chart,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.common,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.cont,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.pivottable,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel,
 org.apache.poi.hssf.util,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.common,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.dev,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.eventfilesystem,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.nio,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.property,
 org.apache.poi.poifs.storage,
 org.apache.poi.ss,
 org.apache.poi.ss.extractor,
 org.apache.poi.ss.format,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.atp,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.constant,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.forked,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.function,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg,
 org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf,
 org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel,
 org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts,
 org.apache.poi.ss.util,
 org.apache.poi.ss.util.cellwalk,`enter code here`
 org.apache.poi.util
```

Second Manifest

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 1
Bundle-Name: poi.ooxml
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.poi.ooxml
Bundle-Version: 3.9
Bundle-Vendor: xyz
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Require-Bundle: org.apache.poi.ooxml.schemas,
 org.apache.poi.dom4j,
 org.apache.poi.xmlbeans
Import-Package: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel
Export-Package: org.apache.poi,
 org.apache.poi.dev,
 org.apache.poi.extractor,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.signature,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.signature,
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util,
 org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel,
 org.apache.poi.util,
 org.apache.poi.xslf,
 org.apache.poi.xslf.extractor,
 org.apache.poi.xslf.model,
 org.apache.poi.xslf.model.geom,
 org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel,
 org.apache.poi.xslf.util,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.dev,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.extractor,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.model,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.charts,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.extensions,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers,
 org.apache.poi.xssf.util,
 org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor,
 org.apache.poi.xwpf.model,
 org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel
```

Comment: Please shwo us the manifest's

Comment: @verbose-mode added the manifest file

Comment: Make sure you added version numbers to all your ex- and imports. Are some packages exported twice, e.g. from other bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: do you really need to convert the poi jars into bundles? If you use the code from only one other bundle, it may be wise to just include the jars into that bundle and adapt the bundle class path accordingly. This may save you a lot of problems, especially if you are not very familiar with converting existing jars to OSGi bundles.

I had a quick look at the poi distribution and the packages may be named the same, but the contents are not the same (split packages). This means that the simplest option here is to create a new bundle jar including all the classes from the poi and poi-ooxml jars from the distribution. Then export all packages from that bundle using the `Export-Package` header.